# Regression when both input and dependent variables are percentages

Tags: regression, experiment-design, percentage

I have a dataset where I am trying to understand if there is a correlation between two variables: an input which is the percentage of a group that is white (which varies between 40% and 95%), and an output which is the annual percentage increase in the housing values for that group (which varies between 0.1% and 10%, e.g. the value of the houses for a neighborhood where the population is 85% white have gone up by 7.5% since last year)

Setting aside for a moment if a linear relationship is at all appropriate for this question, if I ask Excel to plot a scatter plot of X = percentage white and Y = percentage value increase this year, and fit a line, Excel gives me one back: y = 0.0087x + 0.0371. R^2 is 0.0021

Am I correctly interpreting what Excel is telling me - for every percentage point increase of the population mix towards more white, the percentage points for home value increases goes up by 0.087? Or in another way, if there was a neighborhood that was 82% white and if its housing values went up 6% last year, if that neighborhood had been 92% white property values would have gone up 6.87% last year?

I think this is basic question, but I'm just a little lost with percentage increases of percentages and the like. Actually, I'm not even completely sure that this is an allowable question for linear regression, so I'm hoping my example is simple enough that someone can point me in the right direction

Again, I don't actually think the causality here is actually that simple, but before I go on to try to talk about better approaches with more data, I want to make sure that I'm using the math right and explaining what the math is telling me in the basic approach, even if it's not going to give me the "correct" answer of what's really happening with housing prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your R-squared indicates there is no correlation.  Being white is not impacting the increase in value. An R-squared of 1 is a perfect correlation, and an R-squared of -1 is a perfect negative correlation.

It appears you are seeing a scatterplot similar to the bottom image below (or otherwise one where it's hard to draw a line in "middle" of it).

The top image below shows a positive correlation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful, and yeah, the lower image is closer to what I was seeing. One minor followup - if my R-squared had been much closer to 1, would I have been interpreting the percentage point increase correctly from the slope of the equation? I'm still a little confused about the units to use.